# Difference Between .dialog("close") and .dialog("destroy")

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What is the difference between `.dialog("close")` and `.dialog("destroy")` in jquery-ui?

I have a script where the previous developer had used `.dialog("destroy")` but now I've to perform some actions once the dialog is closed. I've found `beforeclose` that is called with `.dialog("close")` and not with `.dialog("destroy")`. So I've to change the method from `destroy` to `close` to make it work.

So is there anything that I'll miss if I use `.dialog("close")` and not `.dialog("destroy")` ?

PS: The dialog is using custom buttons to close itself, and the `.dialog("close")` is called on the click event of the button

Comment: Start here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

Comment: Thankyou @Parsanth that is helpful. I googled alot but found nothing :p .. https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+dialog+close+and+dialog+destroy

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`close` leaves the dialog configured, but invisible, so you can reopen it again with `.dialog('open')`.

`destroy` will completely deconfigure the dialog box.  It'll remove all of the UI elements that were added to the DOM, and any related event handlers.

`destroy` will *not* remove the element that held the *contents* of the dialog box (i.e. the element that you call `.dialog` on)

Comment: I saw a peculiar behavior today. I had two dialogs open, each with separate DIVs and Forms and Fieldsets. When I 'closed' the second one to open, it cleared all the values from the first dialog's input fields! When I 'destroyed' the second one instead, the first dialog was left alone.  Since I rebuild the dialog each time, it was not an issue.

Answer (score 8):

Remember if you are using the dialog for forms input, that destroying it will NOT remove your input, so if you are validating with the :input pseudo selector, the elements you 'destroyed' will be validated. This is where .remove() comes in handy.

You can add a custom close event that destroys your dialog and removes any form inside it to prevent further validation of it.

```
$dialog = $("#your_dialog_id");
$dialog.dialog('option', {
    title: "title",
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $dialog.find("form").remove();
        $dialog.dialog('destroy');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

From [**Docs**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close):

> **destroy:**
>
> Removes the dialog functionality completely. This will return the
>   element back to its pre-init state.
>
> **close:**
>
> Closes the dialog, which can re-opened when needed.