# jQuery modal div contents not refreshing after adding a spinner

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I've got the following code that prompts a user with a jQuery modal as part of address validation:

```
    <div id="modal">
        <% if(SkipBilling.Value != "true")  {%>
        <div>
            <div>The billing address does not appear to be valid. Here is the closest match: </div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdo_SuggestedBillAddr" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <% } %>
        <% if(!chkSameAsBilling.Checked && SkipShipping.Value != "true") { %>
        <div>
            <div> The shipping address does not appear to be valid. Here is the closest match:</div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdo_SuggestedShipAddr" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <% } %>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lblSuggestionSelect"  OnClientClick="closeModal();" OnClick="LbSuggestedAddress_Click" CssClass="Button GrayButton" >Select</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
```

```
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();

function closeModal() {
    jQuery("#modal").dialog("close");
    jQuery("#<%=ModalControl.ClientID%>").val("false");
}

function openModal() {
    jQuery("#modal").dialog("open");
}
function init() {

    jQuery("#modal").dialog({
        title: "Address Suggestion",
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        modal: true,
        width: '500',
        open: function (type, data) { jQuery(this).parent().appendTo("form") },
        autoOpen: false
    });

    var dialogs = jQuery(".ui-dialog");
    if (dialogs.length == 2) {
        dialogs.first().children('#modal').remove();
        dialogs.first().remove();;
    }
}

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_pageLoaded(function (sender, e) {
    init();
    var bool = jQuery("#<%= ModalControl.ClientID%>").val();
    var skipBill = jQuery("#<%= SkipBilling.ClientID%>").val();
    var skipShip = jQuery("#<%= SkipShipping.ClientID%>").val();
    if (bool == "true" && (skipBill != "true" || skipShip != "true")) {
        openModal();
    }
});
```

The above div is wrapped in an UpdatePanel; and this all works fine.  However, I also want to introduce a modal processing spinner.  The code for that is below:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(ConfigureAndShowCheckoutSpinner);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(CloseCheckoutSpinner);

function ConfigureAndShowCheckoutSpinner(s, e) {
    BuildModalDialog();
    AddSpinnerToModal();
    ShowModal();
}
function CloseCheckoutSpinner(s, e) {;
    jQuery('#checkoutSpinner').dialog("close");
}

function BuildModalDialog() {
    jQuery("#checkoutSpinner").dialog({
        title: "Processing",
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
}

function AddSpinnerToModal() {
    var modalDiv = document.getElementById('checkoutSpinner');
    new Spinner().spin(modalDiv);
}

function ShowModal() {
    jQuery('#checkoutSpinner').dialog("open");
}
```

The target div for the spinner is outside of the update panel that wraps the address validation modal.

However, when I put the spinner in place; the spinner part works; but the address validation section doesn't appear to be refreshed.  Stepping through the code & using watch windows I can verify that the fields are updated and the radiobuttonlists have items; they're just not displaying.  Taking out the spinner causes everything to start working again.

I'm stumped on this; what in the spinner would be breaking the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy the dialog.
You can use this to destroy the modal.
`.dialog('destroy')`

When you are using
`.dialog("close")` it is getting hided. The content wont get changed.

> `close` leaves the dialog configured, but invisible, so you can reopen it again with .dialog('open').
>
> `destroy` will completely deconfigure the dialog box. It'll remove all of the UI elements that were added to the DOM, and any related event handlers.
>
> `destroy` will not remove the element that held the contents of the dialog box (i.e. the element that you call .dialog on)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055724/difference-between-dialogclose-and-dialogdestroy)

Comment: Thanks; I'll give this a shot.  I think I've been able to isolate some weirdness to the 2nd half of the init() method.  For some reason adding my spinner is causing something different to happen there.  Unfortunately this code base is new to me; and there's definitely some nuances going on i'm still figuring out.